# Store database settings on .ENV or in a master database. For laravel with multiple dbs, one database per user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

We're starting a Laravel API from scratch where each user has his own MYSQL server (Amazon RDS instance).

The user's databases list will be less than 100 users, so less than 100 databases instances.

We're discussing with my partner because he's storing each server settings in the .env file (APPROACH_1), he has a script that appends the DB settings for each new user, he stores the hostname, user, password... in the .env.

Like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=master_db
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=master_db
DB_USERNAME=master_db_usr
DB_PASSWORD=master_db_pwd

DB_CONNECTION=user_1
DB_HOST="user_1.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=user_1_db
DB_USERNAME=user_1_usr
DB_PASSWORD=user_1_pwd

DB_CONNECTION=user_2
DB_HOST="user_2.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=user_2_db
DB_USERNAME=user_2_usr
DB_PASSWORD=user_2_pwd
...
```

For me, having the settings in the .env is ugly and hard to maintain, I'm suggesting to him to keep the master DB settings in the env. But store the user's databases settings in the master database (APPROACH_2):

[image]

But he says that I'm breaking the laravel framework because laravel database config file  app/config/database.php cannot look for database settings directly on the database, the file expects the settings from the .env file

Is my partner right and we must keep the user's databases settings in the env file??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar approach on a multi-tenant app, and I store data on the database.  Then I have a middleware based on the subdomain that sets up the database configs.

You can use this as an example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Tenant;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SubdomainSetup
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $subdomain = $request->server()['HTTP_HOST'];

        $tenant = Tenant::where('subdominio', $subdomain)->where('habilitado', 1)->first();

        if (!$tenant) {
            dd('Invalid subdomain.');
        }

        config([
            'database.connections.mysql.tenantid' => $tenant->tenantid,
            'database.connections.mysql.host'     => $tenant->host,
            'database.connections.mysql.database' => $tenant->database,
            'database.connections.mysql.username' => $tenant->username,
            'database.connections.mysql.password' => $tenant->password,
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This code changes the config file dynamically so everything is transparent on the Laravel side.

Comment: Setting the conf file dynamically is a good idea, thanks for pointing me to this approach :)